# Change navbar title programmatically

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm working with the Xcode Utility template. In rootViewController.m there's a section that sets up the navbar for what's called the FlipSideView:

(snip)

```
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
```

(snip)

How can you programmatically change the navbar title from within the FlipsideViewController class? I tried:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"XXXXXX";
```

w/o success.

Answer (score 8):

OK, I spent some time on this, because I want to use the convenience of NIB layout for the utility-template app, but I want to be able to internationalize without maintaining a gazillion nibs.

So, the first thing is to add to the FlipViewController class:

`IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBarItself;`

Then, in IB, to control-drag from the Navigation Bar to the File's Owner, and connect to navBarItself in the File's Owner.

Then, the code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    navBarItself.topItem.title = @"Peace!!";
}
```

and this appears to work like a charm

(and it also works when added to ViewDidLoad)

(p.s. the other answers shown here did not work for me)

Comment: Yes it works, and even better if the code is moved to viewDidLoad!

Answer (score 4):

When are you calling that line?  I call the same line in the `ViewDidLoad` method and it works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Test";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

How are you showing your view?  Here is how one of my ViewControllers(tableView) presents the other(detailView)

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you somehow set it up as an IBOutlet?

Comment: Check the edit, you might need to add more information to your question.

Comment: It's a good idea to assert that your IB outlets are not nil. I do this explicitly with: assert(self.tableView != nil); and if it is nil I found out about it pretty fast. Using assert a lot everywhere will ensure what you are thinking is happening is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse's answer should work, but since you're still having troubles, one of the first spots to check is the reference to the navigationItem.

Try debugging your app with a breakpoint on that line, and examine the reference. Most likely, the call is not taking place because the reference is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If your reference is nil, check your connections in IB.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, every subclass of UIViewController has a ‘title’ property which holds the text that is displayed in the navbar title. Thus, setting `self.title = @"Foobar";` in -viewDidLoad or in -viewWillAppear:animated: should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title of the FlipSideViewController to set the title in the navigation controller while the FlipSideViewController is the topViewController. In FlipSideViewController:

```
self.title = "Flip Side";
```

I'm not sure exactly how this project is laid out, but I think this is what you're talking about.